# Instabug Crashed after shaking

Tags: ios, iphone, instabug

I am developing a location based app, Implementing INSTABUG SDK in the app.
But when i shake my iPhone the app crashes.

Can anyone here help me please.. Spent 2 days with it??
Thanks In advance

Below is my device console, at the time of crash:
Thanks in advance :)

```
libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
��Jun 27 15:31:35 iPhone5 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.whosfree.com[0x2000][3070]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.whosfree.com[0x2000]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
��Jun 27 15:31:35 iPhone5 backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.whosfree.com[0x2000]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
��Jun 27 15:31:35 iPhone5 ReportCrash[3072] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/WF_2013-06-27-153134_iPhone5.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Comment: Segmentation fault generally occurs when over release is done. Try running your application with NSZombieEnabled. This will tell you if you're over releasing any object.

Comment: But it happens only when i shake my iphone, It means when call goes to instagram SDK.

Comment: with these logs I can only tell this much, you will have detailed logs once you use NSZombie.

Comment: If you still have any problems with Instabug please send us an email at contactus@instabug.com ... we'd love to help you out